# How to register to GCM and Post to our Server at single attempt?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am successful in registering to GCM server and posting registration id to our server but it is taking two attempts to complete the whole cycle. I need to do all these in single attempt. I am adding my code below please correct me if I am wrong.
First attempt: It will register to gcm server.
Second attempt : It will register to our server

```
protected void RegisterApp() {
    // -----------------------------------
    aServerUtility = (GCMServerController) getApplicationContext();

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!aServerUtility.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        // Internet Connection is not present
        aServerUtility.showAlertDialog(this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }//

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    final String Username = etUserName.getText().toString();

    if (regId.equals("")) {

        // Register with GCM
        GCMRegistrar.register(common_signin.this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);

    } else {

        // Device is already registered on GCM Server
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {

            // Skips registration.

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    regId + " - Already registered with GCM Server",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Registered device (regId = " + regId + ")");


        } else {

            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    try {
                        aServerUtility.register(context, Username, "", regId);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };

            // execute AsyncTask
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------

// Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(
                Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        aServerUtility.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

        // Display message on the screen
        // lblMessage.append(newMessage + "");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        aServerUtility.releaseWakeLock();
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two calls to this method were needed because you only called `GCMRegistrar.register()` when there is no existing registration ID (in `if (regId.equals(""))`). The method ends after that and does not call `aServerUtility.register()`, which performs the server registration. It is only in the second call, when `if (regId.equals(""))` is false, that you actually make the call to register with your server.

Having said all this, please take note that `GCMRegistrar` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html). I would suggest moving to [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).

Comment: Thank you,my issue is resolved.I will look into it and update to new GCM,